# Get all valid attributes for a given XML element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-2.0

I Loaded an XML document inside an `XmlDocument`. The document is loaded by an `XmlReader` that is binded to a given schema (by the `XmlReaderSettings` class).

How can I get a list of allowed attributes for a given document node element?

XML looks like this and has optional attributes:

```
<row attribute1="1" attribute2="2" attribute3="something">
<row attribute1="3" attribute3="something">
<row attribute2="1" attribute3="something">
```

The list should contain attribute1, attribute2, attribute3

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you have some attributes that you want to read and others that should be ignored, don't you? Anyway, you'll need [linq to xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: @PLB I am struck with Visual Studio 2005 and .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 3):

I've used VS2010 but 2.0 Framework.
since you have a schema you know the names of the attributes, I tried with your XML sample just created a base tag.

XML

```
<base>
      <row attribute1="1" attribute2="2" attribute3="something"/>
      <row attribute1="3" attribute3="something"/>
      <row attribute2="1" attribute3="something"/>
</base>
```

CodeBehind

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

        List<string> attributes = new List<string>();

        List<XmlNode> nodes = new List<XmlNode>();
        XmlNode node = xml.FirstChild;
        foreach (XmlElement n in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            XmlAttributeCollection atributos = n.Attributes;
            foreach (XmlAttribute at in atributos)
            {
                if(at.LocalName.Contains("attribute"))
                {
                    attributes.Add(at.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

It give a list with all attributes.

Comment: So you basically suggest to cycle all row elements and build a collection of attributes. The if clause shouldn't be: if(!at.LocalName.Contains("attribute"))?

Comment: Hi. You want the attributes that contains the "attribute" or not? If you don't have LINQ, the only way that I can see is going throught all the nodes.