# c# how to get unknown list of attributes

Tags: c#, xmldocument

When I send request I will get like this response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response result="0">
    <check result="0">
        <extras PRV_TXN_ID="538659" disp1="text1" disp2="text2" disp3="text3"/>
    </check>
</response>
```

I want to show in console list of `disp` attributes. Quantity of `disp` attributes are unknown, depends on requests. Sometimes there will be `disp1.....disp8` . Here in this response there 3 `disp`' attributes and before getting response I didn't know how many are they. How to do that?

Here my Parsing:

```cs
public static XmlDocument postXMLData(string xml)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Requests.url);
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var result = new XmlDocument();
            result.LoadXml(responseText);
            return result;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("что то не так");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all valid attributes for a given XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220115/get-all-valid-attributes-for-a-given-xml-element)

Comment: That's a lot of ceremony for what could be done with a `WebClient.UploadString` call. Using `XElement` rather than `XmlDocument` makes XML processing tasks much easier (`result.Element("response").Element("check").Element("extras").Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("disp")`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for feedback. And how to use XElement in WebClient or in same WebRequest?

Comment: `XElement.ToString()`, `XElement.Parse()`.